# Managing disk space on servers

Tags: linux, disk-usage

Are there any open source tools to view (and possibly restrict) disk usage per user? I need to track disk usage on a server by user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a **quota**. I suggest you start [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=quota+howto).

Comment: I wanted some tool with which i can monitor the disk usage, not specify any upper limit on them. Can this be done using quota as well, i couldnt find it in their documentation

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani If you turn on quotas but don't set a limit, the OS will keep track of storage per user without limiting disk usage.

Comment: you can also get a useful summary listing of usage by all users with 'repquota'.  and if you set up a cron job to save timestamped repquota reports you can generate reports on usage changes over time. and graph them too if that sort of thing appeals to you.